# The $z$-component of the electric field vector

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-fields, maxwell-equations

It is asked to find the wave equation for the z-component of the electric field vector by using Maxwell’s equations in free space.

Here is my work -

In free space we have the following relation between the vectors (in Gaussian system of units):

[image]

[image]

I am trying my hands at calculus based physics. Am I doing it right?